# JavaFX: MenuBar showing "..."

Tags: java, menu, javafx-8

So: i have here a piece of code that I am using to add a menu to my application.

```
Stage window;

private void buildWindow() {
    window = new Stage();
    window.setTitle("FACE");

    //MENU
    MenuBar mBLaunch = new MenuBar();
    Menu fileLaunch = new Menu("File");
    MenuItem saveLaunch = new MenuItem("Save");
    MenuItem exitLaunch = new MenuItem("Exit");
    fileLaunch.getItems().addAll(saveLaunch, new SeparatorMenuItem(), exitLaunch);
    mBLaunch.getMenus().add(fileLaunch);


    //HouseKeeping
    BorderPane bPLaunch = new BorderPane();
    bPLaunch.getChildren().addAll(mBLaunch);
    Scene launch = new Scene(bPLaunch);
    window.setScene(launch);
    window.setMinHeight(500);
    window.setMinWidth(500);
    window.show();

}
```

However: when I run this code it produces:[image: This]

So, my question being, how can I make it display something else than ...?
Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BorderPane places each child at a specific location:  center, top, bottom, left, right.  If you just add nodes to its list of children, it doesn’t know where to place them.

Replace this:

```
bPLaunch.getChildren().addAll(mBLaunch);
```

with this:

```
bPLaunch.setTop(mBLaunch);
```